# Java order of expression evaluation with AND and OR

Tags: java, operators, expression

```
    boolean a = false;
    boolean b = false;
    boolean c = false;
    boolean bool = (a = true) || (b = true) && (c = true);
    System.out.println("" + a + b + c);
```

The prceding code prints `truefalsefalse`. But, the `&&` operator has higher precedence than the `||` operator and should be evaluated first, so why doesn't it print `truetruetrue`?

Comment: Is it on purpose you use assignment `=` and not comparison `==`?

Comment: Yes. It's an example from an OCA mock exam

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I *believe* the crux of your question is this part:

> But, the && operator has higher precedence than the || operator and should be evaluated first

No. Precedence doesn't affect execution *ordering*. It's effectively bracketing. So your expression is equivalent to:

```
boolean bool = (a = true) || ((b = true) && (c = true));
```

... which still executes `a = true` first. At that point, as the result will definitely be `true` and `||` is short-circuiting, the right-hand operand of `||` is not executed, so `b` and `c` are false.

From [JLS section 15.7.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7.1):

> The left-hand operand of a binary operator appears to be fully evaluated before any part of the right-hand operand is evaluated.

Precedence is not relevant to that.

Comment: If it doesn't change the execution ordering, that would explain it. But an exerpt from OCA Java SE 7 Programmer I Certification Guide by Mala Gupta regarding the expression `(a >= 99 || a <= 33 && b == 10)` states that evalation of the expression begins with evaluation of `a <= 33 && b == 10`. Is that incorrect?

Answer (score 3):

`||` is short-circut so its right side will be evaluated only if at left will be `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Because it performs lazy evaluation.

Since `(a = true)` returns `true`, `(b = true) && (c = true)` is never evaluated. And hence you get such an output.

Answer (score 0):

The && and || operators are "short-circuit": they don't evaluate the right hand side if it isn't necessary.

Comment: 2.: Not necessarily, assignments have return values as well. It depends on what he is trying to express with the code.